# Largest sorted list for binary search using 8 comparisons

Tags: binary-search-tree

how do I figure out how to determine the length of a list based on knowing that it is a a merge sort search?

Comment: What is your programming problem?

Comment: `2**8-1` would make sense to me, but it's not hard to test.

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't appreciate your questioning.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson why 2**(8-1) ?  why not 2**8?

Comment: @user3321093 Added an answer with info on the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Not a mathematical proof, but rather simple reasoning;

- With **1** comparison, you can compare **1** item. Not hard to see.
- With **2** comparisons, you can use the first one to split the items in half, and the second one to compare 1 item in either of the halves. That makes 1+1+1 = **3** items comparable.
- With **3** comparisons with the same reasoning, you get 3+1+3 = **7** items comparable.

To generalize, if you can compare **x** items with **n** comparisons, you can compare **x+1+x** items with **n+1** comparisons. This makes the series;

```
1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511...
```

In other words, you can compare 255 items with 8 comparisons.

```
255 = 2**8-1
```